# Exporting Powershell Script to CSV columns

Tags: powershell

We are moving to a new file share location and we are trying to pull all of the current mapped drives on the domain by using a logon script that is utilizing netuse.

I have tried to `export-csv` and it does not return the correct data it just shows the length of what should be there:

`wmic netuse get remotename,username | out-file -append \\PATHTOFILE.csv`

Is the entirety of the script that is running.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1161475/how-to-show-currently-mapped-drives-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Per Ctznkane525's link:

You could try something like this:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object Name,Provider | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File -Append "Path"
```